# How to pull individual values out of $_COOKIE["elementValues"]?

Tags: javascript, php

I have a JavaScript that saves checkboxes state, puts it into a cookie, and then repopulates my checkboxes in my form.  What I am trying to do at this point is put together a bunch of "if statements" with php and then into a string for those that are "true".

Here is what I get when I echo $_COOKIE["elementValues"].  The 1,2,3 represent the id number of each form input checkbox.

```
   {"1":false,"2":false,"3":false,buttonText":""}
```

Here is what I am trying to do with PHP.

```
if ($_COOKIE["1"]=true) 
{ $arguments[] = "AND 2kandunder = 'yes'"; 
}
if ($_COOKIE["2"]=true) 
{ $arguments[] = "AND 2kto4k = 'yes'"; 
} 
if ($_COOKIE["3"]=true) 
{ $arguments[] = "AND 2kandup = 'yes'"; 
}
if(!empty($arguments)) {
$str = implode($arguments);
echo "string: ".$str."<br>;
```

The problem is I echo my $str and even if all the checkoxes are "false" in the $_COOKIE["elementValues"] it will still echo out AND 2kto4k = 'yes'AND 2kandunder = 'yes'AND 2kandup = 'yes'.  How do I write these if statements to add the argument to the string ONLY if that id is "true"?

Here is var_dump($_COOKIE);

```
array(3) { ["PHPSESSID"]=> string(32) "4b4bbcfc32af2f41bdc0612327933887" [2]=> string(6) ""true"" ["elementValues"]=> string(47) "{"1":false,"2":false,"3":false,"buttonText":""}" }
```

{"1":false,"2":false,"3":false,"buttonText":""}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit**

As per your comments, looks like `$_COOKIE["elementValues"]` is a `JSON` string. You'll have to do as per my edit.

---

You are doing assignement where you want to do comparison. Here is your corrected code:

**First**, decode your `JSON` string:

```
$cookie = json_decode($_COOKIE["elementValues"], true); // note the second argument to true to make it an associative array
```

**Then**, do your conditions, either *this* way:

```
if ($cookie["1"] == true) // note the ==
{ 
    $arguments[] = "AND 2kandunder = 'yes'"; 
}
if ($cookie["2"] == true) // note the == 
{
    $arguments[] = "AND 2kto4k = 'yes'"; 
} 
if ($cookie["3"] == true) // note the ==
{
    $arguments[] = "AND 2kandup = 'yes'"; 
}
```

Or *this* way (shorter):

```
if ($cookie["1"]) // casts variable as boolean if it's not
    $arguments[] = "AND 2kandunder = 'yes'"; 

if ($cookie["2"]) // casts variable as boolean if it's not 
    $arguments[] = "AND 2kto4k = 'yes'"; 

if ($cookie["3"]) // casts variable as boolean if it's not
    $arguments[] = "AND 2kandup = 'yes'";
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried both of these examples and this is what I get now.     {"1":false,"2":false,"3":false,"4":false,"5":false,"6":false,"buttonText":""}string: AND 2kto4k = 'yes'.   So even though "2" is false it still is showing 2kto4k in the string?  Also, when I click on a checkbox, for example when I click on checkbox with id one,  the "1" changes to true but it doesn't show in the string?

Comment: What does `var_dump($_COOKIE)` outputs? Post the output in your original question. I bet your `$_COOKIE` is a multidimensionnal array.

Comment: I have editer my answer. If `$_COOKIE["elementValues"]` is an array, you'll have to do as per my edited code. Give it a try.

Comment: Was crossing my fingers it would work but now it goes back to this:  {"1":false,"2":false,"3":false,"buttonText":""}string: AND 2kandunder = 'yes'AND 2kto4k = 'yes'AND 2kandup = 'yes'.     Still shows in string even if it is false?

Comment: We would need `var_dump($_COOKIE)` then as per my previous comment :)

Comment: Looks like `var_dump($_COOKIE["elementValues"])` is a `JSON` string. You'll have to decode it.

Comment: Yikes.  Sounds way above my head.  Thanks for your help I will come back to your examples once I figure out how to decode it.. Would it be easier to decode it or figure out a way to make var_dump($_COOKIE["elementValues"]) not be a JSON string?

Comment: Do `$cookie = json_decode($_COOKIE["elementValues"]);` and check `$cookie` array instead of `$_COOKIE["elementValues"]` which is **not** an array.

Comment: getting this error now: Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array

Comment: Add `true` as a second argument of the `json_decode()` function to make `$cookie` an associative array as per my new edit.